# node js syncronous code execution

Tags: javascript, node.js

Trying to execute the below code synchronously, not sure what I am missing :(,

```
function test (){

    let tableName = process.env.environmentTable || "Appenvironment";
    let environments = [];
    let params = {
        TableName : tableName,
        AttributesToGet : ['environment']
    };

    console.log(2);

    return Promise.resolve(docClient.scan(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.error("Unable to query. Error:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
            //reject (err);
            return err;
        } else {
            console.log(data);
            return data;

        }

    }));    
}



console.log(1);
test().then((data)=>{
    console.log(3);
})
console.log(4);
```

I want to print the numbers orderly like 1234, currently, it is printing like 1243.

How can I make my code to wait until my test function complete?

Comment: What is docClient.scan? When you pass a Promise to `Promise.resolve` it waits until the next Promise is resolved.

Comment: You need to call console.log after the log(3). You can use nested promises.

Comment: Its not a promise, its a dynamo db call once i get the data from db I want to print 3 but till then 4 should not print

Comment: Promises are never synchronous. If you want sequential execution, put the `console.log(4)` in a callback as well. There's no way around this.